# почему $model::deleteAll удаляет данные не за указанную дату yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Ниже 3 функции, 2 вспомогательные `editItems` и `updatingNew` и одна основная `validateEdit`. Основная сохраняет данные в таблицу, но перед этим, чтобы избежать дублирования она делает следующее: `$model::deleteAll(["FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int, '%Y')" => $yearToDelete, "day" => $dayToDelete]);` 
Т.е удаляет все записи из модели за указанный день и год, чтобы избежать дублирования, т.к по ТЗ нельзя сохранять несколько записей за один день и год.

Порой бывает так, что человек сохранив данные за 27 число, переключается на следующую дату и сохраняет данные за 28 число. Вернувшись назад на 27 число он обнаруживает, что либо часть, либо все данные не сохранились и в БД их действительно нет. С чем это может быть связанно и как это можно исправить?

```
/**
 * Функция подхватывает post запрос с формы, обходит его и возвращает массив с текстом и ID
 * @return array
 */
public function editItems() {
    $editNews = Yii::$app->request->post('ThisDay');
    foreach ($editNews["news_name"] as $year => $name) {
        $result[] = $name;
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Функция обновления уже существующей записи в таблице this_day
 * @param integer $id
 * @param string $newsText
 * @param integer $editorId
 * @param integer $timeUp
 * @return array
 */
public function updatingNew($id, $newsText, $editorId, $timeUp) {
    $model = ThisDay::findOne(['id_news' => $id]);
    $model->news_name = $newsText;
    $model->editor_id = $editorId;
    $model->touch($timeUp);
    $model->save();
    return $model;
}

/**
 * Функция валидирует и сохраняет новости в таблице this_day, если запись уже есть - обновляет ее
 * @return array
 */
public function validateEdit() {
    $editNames = $this->editItems();
    //Date -  дата публикации новости в блоке "В этот день...".
    //cdate - дата, когда была сгенерирована конкретная запись для блока "В этот день..." не путать с cdate
    //$model инициализируется в цикле для вставки нескольких элементов в таблицу

    foreach ($editNames as $key => $text) {
        $model = new ThisDay;
        $mkTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', Date::now()), date('d', Date::now()) + 1, date('Y', Date::now()));
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') && !$model->validate()) {
            //$text - массив с выбранными новостями
            //$id - id выбранных новостей
            //$newsText - текст выбранных новостей

            foreach ($text as $id => $newsText) {
                $id = intval($id);
                $thisDayNew = $model::findOne(["id_news" => (int) $id]);
                if (!$thisDayNew) {
                    $model = new ThisDay;
                    $news = News::findNews($id);
                    $yearToDelete = date('Y', $news->cdate_int);
                    $dayToDelete = date('j', $news->cdate_int);
                    $model::deleteAll(["FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int, '%Y')" => $yearToDelete, "day" => $dayToDelete]);
                    $model->news_name = $newsText;
                    $model->old_name = $news->name;
                    $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
                    $model->id_news = $id;
                    $model->editor_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
                    $model->id_region = REGION_ID;
                    $model->cdate = $mkTime;
                    //если новость в таблице - значит она выбрана
                    $model->checked = 1;
                    $timeToSave = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $model->news->cdate_int), date('d', $model->news->cdate_int), date('Y', $model->news->cdate_int));
                    $model->pubDate = $mkTime;
                    $model->cdate_int = $timeToSave;
                    $model->day = date('j', $timeToSave);
                    $model->month = date('n', $timeToSave);
                    $model->save();
                } else {
                    //сохраняет новые данные в модель, если запись уже есть в таблице
                    $updateModel = $this->updatingNew($id, $newsText, Yii::$app->user->id, $model->edate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: так а что вы делаете ? вы циклом добавляете записи в ThisDay 
тоесть первой итерацией вы удаляете все записи за текущий день, потом добавляете запись за текущий день, а потом следуйщими итерациями опять удаляете все записи

Comment: и как вы это вообще делаете ? 

$model = new ThisDay;
$model::deleteAll(["FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int, '%Y')" => $yearToDelete, "day" => $dayToDelete]);

Вызывать статический метод у экземпляра класса ? 
Нужно делать ThisDay::deleteAll(....)

Comment: @madfan41k да, действительно, вероятно в этом ошибка. А почему тогда иногда это работает нормально, а иногда - нет? т.е вот сейчас все вроде в порядке, жалоб нет, но до этого поступали регулярно